# Bulk Insert doesnt insert data when importing text into a date field

Tags: sql-server

It works when I change the field to be varchar but doesn't insert data when the field type is datetime

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
 SET @SQL =N'Bulk Insert tblUsersXTemp 
 from '''+ 
 @filePath + 
 N'''WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ''","'', 
 ROWTERMINATOR = ''"\n'')';

 EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

[image]

Comment: Is this your full sql script / stored procedure? if no, share full sql script.

Comment: what's the datatype of this column in tblUsersXTemp?

Comment: You haven't posted *any* relevant information. No table schema, no file sample. How do you expect SQL Server to guess the date format if you don't specify it in some way? Unless it's an unambiguous format like ISO8601 or the unseparated date format you have to specify which format/locale to use

Comment: I agree with @PanagiotisKanavos.  I don't care what the field looks like in Excel.  I need to know what the format of the actual data file looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is entirely possible that one or more of the records you are trying to bulk insert do not contain valid dates. Sometimes that is a result of using a less common date format, so they might look like good dates. Some countries put the month first instead of the day and that can confuse bulk insert.

Another thing you could try to do if the dates are good is to use a Format file.